# Return specific part of string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to manipulate this following string: `20_hbeu50272359_402_21`

so that I am left with only `hbeu50272359` is there a way to how could I delete those outer numbers? Not sure how to go about it.

The strings  may also take this format:

`hbeu50272359_402_21`

Comment: which lang are you running? show your attempts..

Comment: Jquery this takes off the last ones:  n.replace(/_.*/, '')

Comment: That's because `*` is greedy..

Comment: Are *all* of the strings you need to work with going to be of the form A_B_C_D, where B is what you need?

Comment: `var s = '20_hbeu50272359_402_21';   /_([^_]+)_/.exec(s)[1]; `

Comment: Does it always take the form of `hbeu`?

Comment: @user1937021 I know you've already chosen an answer but I've just updated mine in a way that might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `split`

`"20_hbeu50272359_402_21".split('_')[1]`

The above splits your string based on the `_` char, then use `[1]` to select the part you want (in the returned array or `["20", "hbeu50272359", "402", "21"]`)

This of course would asume that your strings always follow the same format. if not you could use a regEx match with what appears to be a prefix of `hbeu`. Something like `/(hbeu[0-9]+)/` But I'd need more info to give a better approach to the `split` method

UPDATE:

based on your update you could do a regex match like:

```
var stuffWeWant = "20_hbeu50272359_402_21".match(/(hbeu[0-9]+)/)[0];
// this will work regardless of the string before and after hbeu50272359.
```

Comment: If all of the strings will be the same form, and the second part is always the part they need, this works and is the way I'd do it. They haven't really provided enough information in the question to know for sure unfortunately.

Comment: Fully agree. will update with a more robust solution if the OP updates.

Comment: Cant you expand on 'doesn't work'? when I put `"20_hbeu50272359_402_21".match(/(hbeu[0-9]+)/)[0];` in my console I get `hbeu50272359`

Comment: yep. i'm using firefox. what browser are you seeing it fail in?

Comment: sorry you were right it works, thanks very much mate :) appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

`(?!\d)[^_]+` will work on both strings and it doesn't require the second string to start with `hbeu`.

https://regex101.com/r/zF0iR5/3

Comment: With match he would get the correct answer: 
`20_hbeu50272359_402_21".match(/_(.*?)_/)[1]`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `string.replace` function also. ie, replace

- One or more digits plus the following underscore symbol at the start,
- OR
- underscore plus one or more digits followed by another underscore or end of the line anchor

with an empty string.

```
> "20_hbeu50272359_402_21".replace(/_\d+(?=_|$)|^\d+_/g, "")
'hbeu50272359'
> "hbeu50272359_402_21".replace(/_\d+(?=_|$)|^\d+_/g, "")
'hbeu50272359'
```

Answer (score 1):

In general the split solution is better in performance compared to using a regular expression.

Comment: how split will give you the desired output in both cases?

Answer (score 1):

`*` is *greedy*, the engine repeats it as many times as it can, so the regex continues to try to match the `_` with next characters, resulting with matching

```
_hbeu50272359_402_21
```

In order to make it ungreedy, you should add an `?`:

```
_(.*?)_
```

Now it'll match the first `_somecharacters_`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `String.replace()` for that:

```
var s = "20_hbeu50272359_402_21";
var part = s.replace(/.*?_(.*?)_.*/, '$1');
```

The search pattern matches any char `.*` until the next occurrence of a `_`. Using the ungreedy quantifier `?` makes sure it does not match any char until the last `_` in the string. The it captures the text until the next `_` into a capturing group. `(.*?)`. Then the next `_` and the remaining string is matched.

The replace pattern uses `$1` to address the contents of the first capturing group and throws away the remaining match.